# Python: Run a statement that has no effect just to check if exception gets thrown?

Tags: python, exception, pycharm

I want something to happen if user input is not valid (look at the exception block):

```
try:
    name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ")
    table_dictionary[name.title()]  # This is what I am talking about
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name.title() + "?: ")
    print name.title() + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(table_dictionary[name.title()][fact.title()])
except KeyError:
    if name == "x":
        print 'Closing'
        break
    print "Error: Invalid input"
```

Notice how I run `table_dictionary[name.title()]` even though it doesn't do anything. I do this in case the user input is not in the dictionary, it will tell the user that it is invalid input. PyCharm highlights it and tells me that `statement seems to have no effect`. I'm just wondering if this is good practice or not.

Edit: Note that I also want to print "Error: Invalid input" if the user gives invalid input for fact too. My example covers this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more elegant and pythonic:

```
name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ")
if name == "x":
    print 'Closing'
    break
try:
    fact_dictionary = table_dictionary[name.title()]
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name.title() + "?: ")
    print name.title() + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(fact_dictionary[fact.title()])
except KeyError:
    print "Error: Invalid input"
```

This way we catch both possible exceptions for invalid input, and break early if `name == 'x'`

It also makes your code more readable and prevents PyCharm from complaining.

I disagree with some of the other commenters who suggest checking for the keys in the dictionaries and so on, you are right to use exceptions for flow control, [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is the Python way.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for the key in table_dictionary could be a better practice

```
name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ")

if name == "x":
    print 'Closing'
    break
elif name.title() not in table_dictionary:
    print "Error: Invalid input"
else:  
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name.title() + "?: ")
    print name.title() + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(table_dictionary[name.title()][fact.title()])
```

For better readability, you can move .title() directly to the input

```
name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ").title()

if name == "X":
    print 'Closing'
    break
elif name not in table_dictionary:
    print "Error: Invalid input"
else:  
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name + "?: ")
    print name + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(table_dictionary[name][fact.title()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
_ = table_dictionary[name.title()]  # This is what I am talking about
```

because it`s a python convention to use underscore _ to signal that this variable isn't used. Otherwise pycharm would complain about unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

It can be OK to run some code just to see if it raises an exception, but often there's a better way to test if something is possible or not. In your specific case, I'd suggest testing if the key is in the dictionary using the `in` operator, with an `if`, `elif` and `else` to resolve the consequences:

```
name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ")
if name.title() in table_dictionary:
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name.title() + "?: ")
    print name.title() + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(table_dictionary[name.title()][fact.title()])
elif name == "x":
    print 'Closing'
    break
else:
    print "Error: Invalid input"
```

Comment: I should have clarified, I want to run "Error: Invalid input" if the user gives a bad fact too. Your example would not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this. Nothing is useless now.

```
try:
    name = raw_input("\nEnter someone's name (x to exit): ")
    assert name != 'x', "Closing"
    assert table_dictionary.has_key(name.title()), "Error: Invalid input '%s'" % name
    fact = raw_input("What do you want to know about " + name.title() + "?: ")
    assert table_dictionary[name.title()].has_key(fact.title()), "Error: Invalid input '%s'" % fact
    print name.title() + "'s " + fact + " is " + str(table_dictionary[name.title()][fact.title()])
except AssertionError as err:
    print err
```

Comment: You can just write `assert table_dictionary.has_key(name.title())` you don't need `== True`. I do quite like the approach of using assert for this line as I think it is even more explicit, and allows for the `AssertionError` to be handled separately to the `KeyError`. But don't forget that you must also still catch the potential `KeyError` which occurs on the `print` line when looking up the `fact`.

Comment: @rbricheno Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit my answer according to your suggestions.